# WordPress short code position

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning to write a WordPress short code.

In my function I created a big table and some CSS. When I put my short code into posts, the position of the table is always on the top of the posts, regardless of where I put the code in the editor.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcode content should be return. not echo. user below:

```
    function shortcodetest(){   
        return "<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>";
    }
    add_shortcode("shortcode","shortcodetest");
```

Do not use echo :

```
    function shortcodetest(){   
        echo  "<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>";
    }
    add_shortcode("shortcode","shortcodetest");
```